# Admin Column does not populate with data

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, admin

I am new to coding and struggle with the following code. My plan was to add a column to the admin page of a post list. I managed to add the column but struggle with adding the relevant data.

Here is the code:

```
add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns', 'gd_companion_managing_my_posts_columns', 10, 2 );
function gd_companion_managing_my_posts_columns( $columns, $post_type ) {
    if ( $post_type == 'gd_companion' )
        $columns[ 'geodir_email_row' ] = 'Email';
    return $columns;
}


add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'gd_companion_populating_my_posts_columns', 10, 2 );
function gd_companion_populating_my_posts_columns( $column_name, $post_id ) {
    switch( $column_name ) {
        case 'geodir_email_row':
            echo '<div id="geodir_email_row-' . $post_id . '">' 
                . get_post_meta( $post_id, 'geodir_email_row', true ) . '</div>';
        break;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It is unclear from your post what exactly is going wrong. Is no content displayed in the column cells? Is the column not displayed at all? What data should be displayed? Please update your post with the relevant information.